# How can I prove that for any sets A, B, C, D, that $(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D) \subseteq (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tested a few cases and it seems to check out, but I'm not sure how to prove that this statement is true.

$(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D) \subseteq (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup D)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element chase and cases.

Let $x\in (A\cap B) \cup (C\cap D)$.  then either Case 1: $x \in A\cap B$ or Case 2: $x \in C\cap D$ (or both)

Case 1: If $x \in A\cap B$ then $x \in A$.  And since $x \in A$ it will be true that $x$ is either in $A$ or in $C$ (because it *IS* in $A$) so $x \in A\cup C$.  And $x \in B$. And since $x \in B$ it will be true that $x$ is either in $B$ or in $D$ (because it *IS* in $B$) so $x \in B\cup D$.  So $x$ is in both $A\cup C$ and in $B\cup B$.  So $x \in (A\cup C)\cap (B\cup D)$.

Case 2: is done the same way will show that if $x \in C\cap D$ then $x \in (A\cup C)\cap (B\cup D)$.

So either way we will always get that if $x \in (A\cap B)\cup (C\cap D)  \implies x \in (A\cup C)\cap (B\cup D)$.  So that means $(A\cap B)\cup (C\cap D) \subset (A\cup C)\cap (B\cup D)$.

Comment: thanks for the help! I understand now :)

Comment: did you mean to use the subset with the line underneath for your last equation?

Comment: No.  In my book, $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Solving such a question can be done in a systematic way by decomposing into small steps.

First, let $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)$. Our aim is to prove that $x \in (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup D)$.

Our hypothesis $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)$ means that $x \in A \cap B$ or $x \in C \cap D$.

Case 1: $x \in A \cap B$. This means that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$. As $x \in A$ you get also that $x \in A \cup C$. As $x \in B$ you get also that $x \in B \cup D$. Hence $x \in A \cup C$ and $x \in B \cup D$, which yields $x \in (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup D)$.

Case 2: $x \in C \cap D$. It is the same principle. Try it!

Comment: How did you go from:As x∈A you get also that x∈A∪C.

Comment: $x \in A$ implies ($x \in A$ or $x \in C$) and this is the same as $x \in A \cup C$
(Otherwise said, $A \subseteq A \cup C$)

Comment: Oh I think I understand. Could you also say that $x \in A$ implies that $x \in B$ or $x \in C$ or $x \in D$ too? It's just the arguments about B and D aren't useful in that exact place.

Comment: You could say that if $x \in A$ then [$x \in A$ or $x \in B$ or $x \in C$ or $x \in D$] if you want

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that, for any sets $X,Y,Z$,
$$
X\subseteq Y\cap Z\iff (X\subseteq Y \text{ and } X\subseteq Z)\qquad(1)
$$
and
$$
(X\cup Y)\subseteq Z\iff (X\subseteq Z\text{ and }Y\subseteq Z)\qquad (2)
$$
then this problem becomes easy, as follows. The formula you want,
$$
(A\cap B)\cup(C\cap D) \subseteq (A\cup C)\cap (B\cup D),
$$
is equivalent by (1) to
$$
(A\cap B)\cup(C\cap D) \subseteq A\cup C \quad\text{ and }\quad
(A\cap B)\cup(C\cap D) \subseteq B\cup D,
$$
which is in turn equivalent by (2) to
$$
A\cap B\subseteq A\cup C\quad\text{ and }\quad
C\cap D\subseteq A\cup C\quad\text{ and }\quad
A\cap B\subseteq B\cup D\quad\text{ and }\quad
C\cap D\subseteq B\cup D.
$$
The four statements on the last line are all obvious; for example $A\cap B\subseteq A\subseteq A\cup C$.

(If you don't already know (1) and (2), it would be a good idea to prove them. They're easy and often useful.)